# cakephp no login after facebook auth

Tags: facebook-php-sdk, cakephp-2.1

when i create a user with facebook-sdk, i don't get him logged in automaticaly after facebook-login.
Usercreation working well, but no login.

Cakephp and facebook-sdk are latest versions.
here is my accountController:

```
    <?php

class AccountController extends AppController {

    public $uses = array('User');

    public function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Auth->allow('login');
        #$this->Auth->authenticate = array('Basic' => array('fields' =>array('username' => 'fb_id', 'password' => 'random')));

    }

    public function login() {
        $this->facebook = new Facebook(array(
            'appId' => '14549077xxxx',
            'secret' => '95a38f3xxxx',
            'cookie' => 'true'
        ));

        $user = $this->facebook->getUser();
        if($user){
            try{
                $params = array('next' => 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/account/logout');
                $this->Session->write('logoutLink', $this->facebook->getLogoutUrl($params));

                #if (!$this->Auth->user()) {
                    $fb_user = $this->facebook->api('/me');

                    $authUser = $this->User->findByFbId($user);

                    if (empty($authUser)) {
                        $pw = $this->__randomString();
                        $authUser = array(
                            'fb_id' => $user,
                            'random' => $pw,
                            'password' => $this->Auth->password($pw),
                            'email' => $fb_user['email'] 

                        );
                        $this->User->create();
                        $this->User->save($authUser);
                        $authUser = $this->User->findByFbId($user);
                    }

                    $this->Auth->authenticate = array(
                        'Form' => array(
                                'fields' => array('username' => 'fb_id', 'password' => 'random')
                        )
                    );

                    $this->Auth->login($authUser['User']);

                    $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
                #}
            }catch(FacebookApiException $e){
                $user = NULL;
            }
        }
        if(empty($user)){
            $loginurl = $this->facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
                'scope'=> 'email,publish_stream,read_friendlists',
                'redirect_uri'  => 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/account/login',
                ));

            $this->redirect($loginurl);
        }
    }

    public function dashboard() {
        echo 'logged in';
    }
}
```

Users will always get redirect to login page.
$authUser is always filled correctly.

Pls Help :)

Greetings
m.

Answer (score 1):

my AppController

```
class AppController extends Controller {

    public $components = array('Auth','Session');

    public function beforeFilter() {
        $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'account', 'action' => 'dashboard');
        $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = '/';
        $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'login');
    }
```

Sessions:

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
        'defaults' => 'php'
    ));
```

Answer (score 1):

problem solved in chat:

Facebook is creating a new session,

```
$this->facebook = new Facebook(array(
            'appId' => '14549077xxxx',
            'secret' => '95a38f3xxxx',
            'cookie' => 'true'
        ));
```

this code has to written down in appcontroller

```
public function beforeFilter() {
        $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'account', 'action' => 'dashboard');
        $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = '/';
        $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'login');
        $this->facebook = new Facebook(array(
            'appId' => '14549077xxx',
            'secret' => '95a38f3xxx',
            'cookie' => 'true'
        ));

    }
```

Thank you so much @noslone for trying together :D

Answer (score 0):

Providing data `$this->Auth->login($authUser['User']);` to log a user in is wrong.

As per CakePHP documentation:

`In 2.0 $this->Auth->login($this->request->data) will log the user in with whatever data is posted, whereas in 1.3 $this->Auth->login($this->data) would try to identify the user first and only log in when successful.`

You should do something like this:

```
$this->request->data['User'] = $authUser['User'];
$this->request->data['User']['password'] = $authUser['User']['random'];

$this->Auth->login();
```

I have also added `$this->request->data['User']['password'] = $authUser['User']['random'];` because i think it fails to authenticate when providing the encrypted password to login.

Comment: still not working. after login debug($this->Auth->User('fb_id')); returns fb_id parameter. but user will get redirected to login page and there debug($this->Auth->User('fb_id')); returns null. AuthComponent is included.

Comment: What type of session are you using (Session.defaults) and does the session work correctly? And have you tried to add `$this->Auth->loginRedirect = "/page/after/successfull/login";`

Comment: added appcontroller and sessions from core.php

Comment: What is the output of `$this->Auth->user();` after `$this->Auth->login();`

Comment: its filled with the data from database: array(
 'password' => '*****',
 'id' => '7',
 'fb_id' => '1000006xxx',
 'email' => 'xxx@gmx.net',
 'random' => 'STkXS5rSkO146gPBAt8M'
) but its empty after redirecting.

Comment: In that case i think your session doesn't work correctly. Try to set `'defaults' => 'php'` to `'defaults' => 'cake'`

Comment: Have you checked the CakePHP logs (/tmp/logs/)? Maybe there are some errors.

Comment: no errors for this issue :/ there are no informations about this error, no output message, no log entries. nothing :(

Comment: now i tried to work with debug_kit Plugin. if activated, my app works fine, login into dashboard works and a session is created. but when i deactivate this plugin and logout, i cant login again. same problem :(

Comment: yes, there are 2 cookies: PHPSESSID and CAKEPHP. even when both are deleted, after visit my page, they existing again.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22463/discussion-between-noslone-and-heike-rat)

Answer (score 0):

If you have any other trouble, I am developing a Plugin that uses Facebook oAuth as an authentication object for Auth Component. If you want an already-built solution that uses server-side Facebook login, please check my website: http://marianofino.github.com/Facebook-Plugin-for-CakePHP/